# "npm install -g n" then Error: npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

Tags: node.js, windows-10

My aim is to update Node.js to the latest.

I followed the instructions on [this page](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version).

I got the error when executing `npm install -g n`:

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@6.7.0: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

I don't know what that means.

Comment: *"Unsupported platform"* means you can't run it on your OS - [*"(Note: n is not supported natively on Windows.)"*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)

Comment: If you need a Node version manager for Windows, you can use [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Comment: You might be able to run it under [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) on Windows. Another option is a Docker container or a VM of some kind.

Comment: Came here knowing what the error meant, but hoped to find a solution. Found an article here (https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version) that clearly shows you CAN use "n" on windows. Apparently support for WIN32 has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can still install newest/needed version of Node.js on Windows by downloading it from: https://nodejs.org/en/download/